# C++ Boost - no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'boost::filesystem::path'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, lan

I'm building a client/sever application for sending files over the lan. This is the sever application and I get the following error on my code when I'm about to get the file name.

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'boost::filesystem::path' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

#include "stdafx.h"
#ifdef _WIN32 
# define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 
#endif 
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 
#include <boost/array.hpp> 
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp> 
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <iostream> 

std::string filename; 
std::string file; 
boost::asio::io_service io_service; 
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 9999); 
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint); 
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_service); 
boost::array<char, 4096> buffer; 

void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) { 
    if (!ec || ec == boost::asio::error::eof){ 
        std::string data(buffer.data(), bytes_transferred); 
        if (filename.empty()) { 
            std::istringstream iss(data); 
            std::getline(iss, filename); 
            file = data; 
            file.erase(0, filename.size() + 1); 
            filename = boost::filesystem::path(filename).filename(); 
        } 
        else  
            file += data; 
        if (!ec) 
            boost::asio::async_read(sock, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), read_handler); 
        else { 
         //code
    } 
}
```

//code

Comment: filename = boost::filesystem::path(filename).filename();  are you that file name () is not also a path ... look if you could convert that to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
filename = boost::filesystem::path(filename).filename();
```

to this:

```
filename = boost::filesystem::path(filename).filename().string();
```

Basically the compiler is telling you that `std::string` does not define any assignment operator that takes a `boost::filesystem::path` as a parameter (or that there is no conversion it can make that will provide a type it can use as a parameter for the assignment operator). Luckily, `boost::filesystem::path` provides a function that returns a string!